# для чего нужен атрибут tabindex?

Tags: html5

Я сам не понимаю для чего он нужен, я новичок совсем

Comment: [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: если кратко - для выстраивания порядка переключения инпутов(по нажатию кнопки `tab`) отличного от стандартного.

Answer (score 2):

Представь, что у тебя есть форма для заполнения данных. В этой форме есть поля ввода. Обычно мы заполняем одно поле и перемещаемся на следующие поле при помощи мышки. В html `tabindex` служит тем же перемещением только при помощи кнопки `Tab` на клавиатуре. Мы можем указать в атрибут числовое значение для определения последовательности.

В данном примере перемещение будет осуществляться по порядку:

```
<input type='text' tabindex='1' placeholder='Введите имя'>
<input type='email' tabindex='2' placeholder='Введите почту'>
<input type='password' tabindex='3' placeholder='Введите пароль'>
```

---

Отвечая на сам вопрос для чего нужен - для удобства.